# Spring Cloud function cannot read function definition from Message header

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-function

I've created an AWS Lambda based Spring Cloud Function with multiple functions and it works fine when I define exactly one "spring_cloud_function_definition" environment variable in the AWS Lambda Configuration panel. These functions' input and output is a **Message<?>**, so the payload and http headers can be accessed runtime as well.

I'd like to use this AWS Lambda function in different API Gateway methods, so for example:

- /item [POST] -> saveItem should be called
- /item [DELETE] -> deleteItem should be called
- ... and so on...

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-function/3.0.0.RC1/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_function_catalog_and_flexible_function_signatures

I found this documentation on Spring.io which says it's feasible:

> If the input argument is of type Message<?>, you can communicate routing instruction by setting one of spring.cloud.function.definition or spring.cloud.function.routing-expression Message headers. For more static cases you can use spring.cloud.function.definition header which allows you to provide the name of a single function (e.g., …​definition=foo) or a composition instruction (e.g., …​definition=foo|bar|baz)

So the following test event should run in AWS Lambda without any failure:

{
"method": "POST",
"body": "{ "key" : "value" }",
"headers": {
"spring.cloud.function.definition": "saveItem"
}
}

but of course it throws an exception:

```
 No function defined: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No function defined
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.apply(AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.java:187)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootRequestHandler.java:51)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler.java:43)
```

I've tried many configurations (application.properties, AWS Lambda env property, header, etc.) but nothing happened:

- spring.cloud.function.routing-expression=headers.function_name
- setting spring.cloud.function.definition=saveItem

What could be the problem? What is the best configuration in this case? Any help would be appreciated!

**Used technologies:**

- Cloud: **AWS**
- Cloud components: **Lambda + API Gateway**
- AWS Lambda handler class: **org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler**
- AWS Lambda input and output events: **APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent**
- Java: **8**
- Spring Cloud Function version: **3.0.6.RELEASE**

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. It is a bit difficult to determine what is going on even though your explanation seem to be full of details. I'll take a look and see if I can spot something, meanwhile, can you please try [this example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/main/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-aws-routing). This will help to establish the base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated to v3.1.3 and switched to FunctionInvoker and I've added the function definition to the request template mapping header, and it worked fine.

Anyways, thanks for the help. :)